# add item directly in the event, no pop ups addGiftRegistry ()

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, magento-1.8

I am developing a gift list in which when I have more than one event opens a popup to select the event and add the item to the list chosen on click. But as I have only one event I would like to add the item directly without pop up, only I'm not able to move the item to the list, someone could help me with this part?

```
<div id="adjgiftreg_popup" style='display: none;'>
    <div class='box base-mini'>
        <div class='head'>
            <h4><?php echo $this->helper('adjgiftreg')->__('Add to Registry') ?></h4>
            <div class="btn-close">
                <a href="#" onclick="$('adjgiftreg_popup').hide(); return false;"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/btn_window_close.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Close') ?>" /></a>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class='content'>
            <p>
                <?php //sends to the function ?>
            <?php foreach ($this->getEvents() as $event): ?>
            <a href="#" onclick="return addToGiftRegistry(<?php echo $event->getId()?>)"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($event->getFullTitle())?></a>
            <br/>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 


<script>
var baseRegistryLink = '';

function showRegistries(link){
    baseRegistryLink = link;
<?php if ($this->getEvents()->count() > 1): ?>
    $('adjgiftreg_popup').show();
<?php else: ?>
    addToGiftRegistry(0);
<?php endif ?>
    return false;
}
//function parameter receives and verifies number of events

function addToGiftRegistry(e){
    baseRegistryLink = baseRegistryLink + 'event/' + e;
    var form = $('product_addtocart_form');
    var oldFormLink = form.action;
    if (form){
        form.action = baseRegistryLink;
        if(!productAddToCartForm.submit()) {
            form.action = oldFormLink;
        }
    }
    else{
        document.location.href = baseRegistryLink;
       }

    return false;
}

</script>
```

note:staff do not know if you can well express my doubts because my English is terrible, but I hope someone can help me and intenda, thank you!

Comment: `if(jQueryObject)` will always be truthy and `action` isn't a valid property of a jQuery object. Be careful mixing native DOM javascript with jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got some results with this change.

```
function showRegistries(link) {

    baseRegistryLink = link;

    <?php if ($this->getEvents()->count() > 1): ?>
    $('adjgiftreg_popup').show();
    <?php else: ?>

    <?php foreach ($this->getEvents() as $event): ?>
        addToGiftRegistry(<?php echo $event->getId()?>);
    <?php endforeach ?>

    <?php endif ?>

    return false;

}
```

if someone has any tips for improvement, thank you.